# How do I invite a friend to play a game with me using the Steam Client?

Tags: steam

For any game that we both own on Steam, I don't see the option anywhere within the Steam client to invite someone on my Steam friends list to play a game with me. This is the only menu I see when I right-click my friend in my friend's list.

[image]

How can I invite a friend to my game using the Steam Client?

Comment: I disagree that this should have been closed. I've edited your post slightly, and reopened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game should support multiplayer and it will only usually let you invite a friend to play when you are in a suitable section of the game, such as a multiplayer lobby or a game that has an in-game option enabled that lets friends join you. If, for example, you are in the main menu of a game, it usually will not let you invite a friend (unless that main menu shows you in-game that you can invite friends).

Comment: The exception here is games where a party connects with each other before entering any kind of lobby, so that they can then group join a lobby.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however you should clarify that you essentially *cannot* invite a friend to play with you outside of the game itself. Steam does not have that ability at all, apparently.